# How fix error gradle-plugin:compileKotlin in React Native 0.72.6

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (57, 42): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (57, 42): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (57, 59): Class 'kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt__CollectionsJVMKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/collections/CollectionsKt__CollectionsJVMKt.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (60, 72): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (60, 72): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (75, 38): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (75, 38): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (81, 76): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (81, 76): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (85, 42): Class 'kotlin.reflect.KClass' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/reflect/KClass.class
e: F:\ICANFLY\React_Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native\gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\ReactExtension.kt: (85, 42): Class 'kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/khong/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.4-all/56r6xik2f6skrm47et0ibifug/gradle-8.4/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.10.jar!/kotlin/jvm/JvmClassMappingKt.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app.

Last month i use version 0.68.2 not show any error when runnig. And Now i install laster version and can't runnnig my project on android ?

Comment: can you share your android/build.gradle file ?

Comment: buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.0"
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: comment the lines with kotlin version and this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the kotlin lines or comment them and this should work for version 0.72.6.

```html
buildscript { 
ext { 
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0" 
minSdkVersion = 24 
compileSdkVersion = 33 
targetSdkVersion = 33 

ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620" 
} 
repositories { 
google() 
mavenCentral()
} 
dependencies { 
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle") 
classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin") 
} 
}
```

Comment: Okay i will try this.

Comment: @HoàngHạc were you able to solve with this ?

Comment: Yeh , thank you.

Comment: can you mark my answer as accepted

Comment: Oke, this first time i use stack overflow up my question. Sorry.

Comment: Its okay.... Thanks @HoàngHạc